# How display badge on row elements without overlap

Tags: flutter

I want to use [badges](https://pub.dev/packages/badges) package to display a badge on items in a Row but like in the screen below the next element is draw on top of the badge.

[image: Row with overlapping badges]

[image: cropped image badge overlap]

```dart
Row(
  children: List.generate(
    7,
    (index) => Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
        child: Badge(
          badgeContent: Text('a'),
          child: Container(
            color: Color((Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(1.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

I expect the badge to be displayed on top of all the elements

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't obtain the effect you want with that package because the badge is rigorously connected to the child Container so it doesn't have control over others UI elements.
I think that you need to set a margin so each element has the necessary space to being showed.

Comment: Thanks a lot how can I get this effect with without this package then with a stack and positioning with absolute positions ?

Comment: Why do you want obtain that effect? It is not something is used to do, because each widget should have his space, so if the badge it's related to a column, it's like you are not giving at each widget it's "vital space". Are badge related to the column? Right?